# How to pass user form data into defined class

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

I am newbie to Blockchain. I am just trying build a blockchain after watching a youtube video.

app.js:

```
const SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

class Block {
    constructor(data, previousHash = ''){
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.data = data;
        this.hash = this.calculateHash();
    }

    calculateHash(){
        return SHA256(this.previousHash + JSON.stringify(this.data)).toString();
    }
}

class Blockchain{
    constructor(){
        this.chain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
    }

    createGenesisBlock(){
        return new Block("Genesis Block", "0");
    }

    getLatestBlock(){
        return this.chain[this.chain.length - 1];
    }

    addBlock(newBlock){
        newBlock.previousHash = this.getLatestBlock().hash;
        newBlock.hash = newBlock.calculateHash();
        this.chain.push(newBlock);
    }

    isChainValid(){
        for(let i = 1; i < this.chain.length; i++){
            const currentBlock = this.chain[i];
            const previousBlock = this.chain[i - 1];

            if(currentBlock.hash !== currentBlock.calculateHash()){
                return false;
            }

            if(currentBlock.previousHash !== previousBlock.hash){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

let xyzcOin = new Blockchain();

xyzcOin.addBlock(new Block({amount: 8}));
xyzcOin.addBlock(new Block({amount: 80}));

// console.log("Is blockchain is valid? " + xyzcOin.isChainValid());

// xyzcOin.chain[1].data = {amout: 100};

// console.log("Is blockchain is valid? " + xyzcOin.isChainValid());

console.log(JSON.stringify(xyzcOin, null, 4));
```

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>xyzcOin Blockchain</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="input">
            <form method="post">
                <label for="data">Please enter data:</label>
                <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
                <button type="submit" onclick="addData()">Add Data</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="result">
            <h4>Blocks Added</h4>
            <ul onload="appendData()">
                <li>Block 1:</li>
                <li>Block 2:</li>
                <li>Block 3:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="validate">
            <button type="submit">Validate Chain</button>
            <p>Chain validated? true or false</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Query:

1) User entered data should be taken as data for a block(on submitting add data button) and it should append to listitem dynamically after data entered in above textbox.

2)To validate the blockchain for any tampering, I have created a button to validate the chain and result should be shown.

I get my expected results while I pass data through `console.log()`, but I need this to be done dynamically from html page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `onclick="addData()"` do?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful. I edited the html because you don't want to do the post from the form tag. You just want to get the user input and send that to your js so it can fetch the data. Then you can update the html with the response from the fetch.

1. User inputs text into form and presses enter or clicks button
2. triggers a js function that does a post
3. on success you now have the response object in the .then and you can update the dom

here is a reference to using the fetch api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```js
// select the form
const formData = document.querySelector('.form-data');

// attach an event listener
formData.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault(); 

  const inputVal =  evt.target[0].value;

  // enter url as first arg and data as second arg
  postData('http://example.com/answer', { data: inputVal })
  .then(data => {
     // JSON from `response.json()` call
    // do something with the data
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
})

// helper function for making posts with fetch api 
function postData(url, data) {
  return fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data), 
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST', 
  })
  .then(response => response.json()) // parses response to JSON
}
```

```html
<form class="form-data">
    <label for="data">Please enter data:</label>
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
    <button type="submit">Add Data</button>
</form>
```

Comment: that wasn't part of your original question. I would need more info to help out with that. 

do you even need to make the ajax request or do you just need the input value?

what does the object look like that you need to append to the list?